# updating data in a list onchange of a drop down and when completed sending the data to servlet

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, onchange

I am fetching data in an arraylist and displaying it in JSP , some of the fields have drop down values and in JSP i can update \ change some values of the drop down ,

My requirement is when I change dropdown values ( more than one ) of multiple fields I should be able to submit updated list to servlet.

Please suggest how can i keep on adding multiple vales to an ArrayList onchange of a dropdown and then when all the the proper values are selected ,I should be able to submit the new arraylist to a servlet for further processing .

Answer (score 0):

If I get your question correctly, you want to select maultiple values from a dropdown then why dont you select a multiselect type of box where in the values selected are mapped to your bean property and sent to your servlet.

you can try this html tag

```
<select id="country" name="country" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="US">United Stated</option>
    <option value="CHINA">China</option>
    <option value="SG">Singapore</option>
    <option value="MY">Malaysia</option>
</select>
```

using spring form you can do it with below tag

```
<form:select path="country" items="${countryList}" multiple="true" />
```

for struts you can use following

```
<html:select property=”selectedValues” multiple=”true” size=”5″>
<html:option value=”0″>Select Country</html:option>
<html:optionsCollection  property=”countryList” label=”countryName” value=”countryId” />
</html:select>
```

suppose you have the input form with a array selectedvalues and countrylist with dropdown values. When you will chose selectedvalues will have the required selected inputs.

Comment: I have multiple drop downs , so I can select multiple values - can you share sample code which I can refer

Comment: are you using spring form or normal form?

Comment: Using Struts 1.0 for this requirement